# Copy list to clipboard in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I have a list named `final` and I want to copy it to the clipboard. I want every element in the list to be a line. (Ex: ["foo", "bar"] into 2 lines *foo* and *bar*) I've tried pyperclip, but it doesn't support lists.

Comment: how do you want to copy it into the clipboard?

Comment: @RyanSchaefer I do not understand your question. I want to copy it to the clipboard normally

Comment: i mean do you want it line separated or space separated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like `pyperclip.copy("\n".join(final))` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use pyautogui

```
import pyautogui

test = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']

for word in test:
    pyautogui.typewrite(word + '\n')
```